# Skip first line with Python stdin?

Tags: python, io, stdin

I would like to read lines from the python stdin implementation. so far I have:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    process line
```

but I would like to skip the first line that is supplied.

Python has a method for this when using the fileinput implementation which returns true if it is the first line and false otherwise

```
fileinput.isfirstline()
```

Ideally there would be something like that for stdin where I could go:

```
if sys.stdin.isfirstline():
     process(first line)
else:
     process everthing else
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try sys.stdin.next() to skip? This should work in Python 3

Comment: @Eyrofire that's useful thanks, how would you get the line number though? I looked it up but couldn't find that either

Comment: You could use `for index, line in enumerate(sys.stdin): if index:`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to keep track of the line number:

```
for linenum, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    if linenum != 0:
        process line
```

Comment: That should just be `if i`, or *possibly* `if i != 0`, but certainly not an identity test, which leaves you relying on interning, an implementation detail.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, I am not familiar enough with python - what is an identity test? is that like comparing two objects against one another whereas `if i != 0` compares the two basic or something? thanks
regardless, both your and Darrick Herwehe solutions solved my problem, thanks

Comment: @Cole `a is b` checks whether they *are the same object*, whereas `a == b` checks whether they *have the same value*. Try e.g. `100 * 10 is 1000` vs `100 * 10 == 1000`. In this case, `if line:` also works because Python evaluates an empty iterable (`[]`, `""`, etc.) as `False`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're right. I jump between Python and Applescript a lot, and sometimes forget that doesn't mean the same thing in both languages.